# LDPC:How to detect total number of errors in a codeword using minimum distance?

Tags: encoding-scheme, hamming-code

Currently, i working with LDPC for FPGA implementation. I have formed H matrix of size 102X204 (N=204,K=102,M=102,R=0.5). Doubt in Error detection and correction for bigger matrix.

I know that code's error detecting and correcting capability depends on its DISTANCE. For example distance is say 10, then i can correct maximum of (10 - 1)/2 = 4 errors and detect maximum 10 - 1 = 9 errors. But i don`t know how to find the number errors in a codeword N=204.

Comment: The number of errors in a codeword is the distance to the closest codeword.

Comment: I need explanation with example.